# как делать отступы после переноса строки в Text tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, текст

Можно ли в tkinter реализовать возможность автоматически добавлять отступы после переноса строки?
Если да, то как?

Например мы ввели
   `текст`

И нужно чтобы после того как мы нажали ENTER, добавилось такое же количество пробелов, что и в предыдущей строке  `...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообщем-то как-то так. но надо сильно допилить. Если что — спрашивайте в комментах.

```
import tkinter as tk
import re

root = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text(root)
text.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

def autoindent(event):
    # the text widget that received the event
    widget = event.widget

    # get current line
    line = widget.get("insert linestart", "insert lineend")

    # compute the indentation of the current line
    match = re.match(r'^(\s+)', line)
    current_indent = len(match.group(0)) if match else 0

    # compute the new indentation
    new_indent = current_indent + 4

    # insert the character that triggered the event,
    # a newline, and then new indentation
    widget.insert("insert", event.char + "\n" + " "*new_indent)

    # return 'break' to prevent the default behavior
    return "break"

text.bind(":", autoindent)

root.mainloop()
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60659212/how-can-i-add-an-auto-indent-feature-after-colon-in-tkinter-gui-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Я составил небольшой код

```
from tkinter import *
c=Tk()
text1=''
tabs=0
def tab(event):
   global tabs,text1
   tabs=0
   back_line=(text1.get('insert linestart','insert lineend'))
   for i in back_line:
      if i== ' ':
         tabs+=1
      else:
         break
   cut=' '*(tabs)
   text1.insert('insert','\n')
   text1.insert('insert',(cut))
   return 'break'
text1=Text(c,wrap='none')
text1.pack(fill=BOTH)
text1.bind('<Return>',tab)
c.mainloop()
```

(Для тех кто в такой-же ситуации)